# PHP/JS - Realtime Form

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I dont want it to validate anything e.t.c I just want it to for example grab whatever the user entered in the username field and then place whatever the user entered somewhere in the HTML in realtime. No reloading the page e.t.c. Can this be done?

Currently im using a basic PDO form to insert data into my database and I need this for just visual and synthetic look if its not possible then it wont really bother me much it would just suck :(

Also im not sure if this would be Javascript or PHP so please dont kill me that I tagged both :P

Update:
I tried adding: `<script>$('input[name="imdbid"]').change(function(){ alert($('#userimdb').attr('href')+$('input[name="imdbid"]').val()); });</script>`

After the PDO script but it didnt seem to do anything. My form was echoed from the PDO php script so maybe thats why and the HTML im trying to add this javascript to is before the  tag containing this JS but im almost sure that doesnt make a difference. Im not good at all with JS so any ideas?

Update:
I also tried:

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["imdbid"].value;
    change($('#userimdb').attr('href')+$x;
```

But that doesnt work either

Comment: If you want it to happen without a page reload, it's going to have to be done with Javascript - PHP won't run again until a page loads. Can you set up a quick jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) with the relevant parts of your HTML?

Comment: @Mike original name lel anyway http://jsfiddle.net/fe0a158L/ has my HTML

Comment: It seems no JS was working no matter what because i had a extra div that loaded a bit more then half th epage, JQuery was at the end before body so thats why, But still the JS i tried above arent working.

Comment: <script>$('input[name="imdbid"]').change(function(){ alert($('#userimdb').attr('href')+$('input[name="imdbid"]').val()); });</script> will tell me what the href should be changed to but when I take off alert() it doesnt do a thing but its meant to change the href

Comment: Does this help?: https://jsfiddle.net/fe0a158L/4/

Comment: I thought this question was dead or something cause no replies so I got an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224927/js-dynamic-href-change/31224944 but I think that wouldve done the trick

Comment: Not having any replies for a few hours isn't anything unusual.