# JS - Dynamic Href Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Ive tried many way but im new to JS, I mainly do PHP.

Anyway the code:

```
    <script>
        var userinput = $('input[name="imdbid"]');

        userinput.change(

        function(){
            $('#userimdb').attr('href')+$('input[name="imdbid"]').val();
        }

        );
</script>
```

Basically, the imdbid is gotten from a input tag, basically I want to append whatever the user types to a href of a  tag, This doesnt seem to work doe. When I alert() it, it seems to give me the output of what its meant to but when I remove alert() it doesnt seem to change the href, I also tried .setAttribute() but that also just did nothing.

Please help me out im going insane right now.

Comment: You're not assigning a new value to `href` attribute anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the attribute right now, only accessing it. In addition, you need to store the original href attribute somewhere so you're not adding the same text repeatedly. Here's the updated code:

```
var userinput = $('input[name="imdbid"]');
var orighref = $('#userimdb').attr('href');
userinput.change(function(){
    $('#userimdb').attr('href', orighref + userinput.val());
});
```

Comment: This work perfect aswell, But Rayon's one is a smaller and more compact.

Comment: @Kyubeh2435436 Try clicking away and then changing the textbox again using Rayon's solution; it'll add the text twice (the old text and the new text).

Comment: yh, Thats why I moved to your answer it solved that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

You need to assign it to **href** attribute..

```
var userimdb=$('#userimdb');
var baseURL=userimdb.attr('href');
$('input[name="imdbid"]').change(function()
{
    var userimdb=$('#userimdb');
    userimdb.attr('href', baseURL + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: No dude, Bring it back to your original answer, It was much smaller and worked perfect.

Comment: @RayonDabre You shouldn't ask for acceptance when the OP has already accepted previous answers. It's best to only ask if they may not already know.

Comment: @kyubeh2435436, this one is more optimized..I have removed redundant Jquery selector..

Comment: @RayonDabre, you can make it even more optimized my removing "userinput" variable assignment operation, and by using the concept of jquery chaining something like this "$(<input_element>).change(..., as that variable is not used anywhere else.

Comment: @RayonDabre problem. When they change there input it just appends to the url instead of rewriting the old input they made and adding the new one. Anyway we can fix that?

Comment: @RayonDabre Pluto's answer solves this. The answer mark is going to his answer sowwy :3

Comment: @RayonDabre Ill keep plutos answer as the solved one since he did make the answer first and your answer is almost exactly the same